# NSUserDefaults to Save int - Simple fix

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults

The error I am getting is `cannot invoke '>' with an argument list of type '(() -> (), Int)'`

The code works if `var score = 0` is inside the score function.

Where exactly should I store this function for this to work, I am planning to make a button and when it is clicked the `myScore` label text is changed to `String(score)`so it will display on the score. I'm new to NSUserDefaults so go easy :)

```
import UIKit

var score = 0

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var myScore: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

func score() {
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().integerForKey("highscore")

    //Check if score is higher than NSUserDefaults stored value and change NSUserDefaults stored value if it's true
    if score > NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().integerForKey("highscore") {
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setInteger(score, forKey: "highscore")
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
    }

    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().integerForKey("highscore")

}
override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


}
```

Comment: where is the actual problem?

Comment: `if score > NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().integerForKey("highscore")` the `>` is what is triggering it. @AdeelUrRehman

Comment: try to get `NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().integerForKey("highscore")` in a variable like `highScore` and check whether the value coming from the defaults is correct or not.

Answer (score 2):

Type errors in Swift can be a little misleading, but this one makes sense.

> cannot invoke '>' with an argument list of type '(() -> (), Int)'

Means you can't call the `>` function (yes, it's a function) with a left hand side value of type `() -> ()` and a right hand side value of type `Int`.

The left hand side is a function type that takes no parameters and returns nothing - and you've got a function called `score` that does just that.

The compiler is using the function instead of the global variable with the same name. You should change the name of the `score()` function - it's vague and unclear anyway.

You may also want to make the `score` variable a property rather than a global variable, but that's a separate issue and not directly relevant to this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your function name and that variable name are similar.That's why you are getting this error.
Change anyone of them.

Also why are you just calling:

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().integerForKey("highscore")
```

You are not assigning the value or returning it, then why are you calling it several times ?

Change your method like:

```
func highScore() -> Int
{
    var highScore = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().integerForKey("highscore")

    //Check if score is higher than NSUserDefaults stored value and change NSUserDefaults stored value if it's true
    if score > highScore
    {
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setInteger(score, forKey: "highscore")
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
        highScore = score
    }
    return highScore;
}
```

Comment: how would I get the `@IBAction func button(sender: AnyObject) {
        score++
        myScore.text = String(score)
        setHighScore()
    }` to display on the screen if the user gets up to 5, where they can close the app and they don't have to restart at 0? @MidhunMP

Comment: @JustinRose: I have updated the code: You can call `highScore()` It'll return the highScore each time

Comment: where do I call the highScore function, within the `viewDidLoad()` ? Thank you so much for the help @MidhunMP

Comment: @JustinRose: In the `viewDidLoad`